# Django Model/Template Arithmetic Issue

Tags: python, django, math

I'm kinda new to Django and I'm trying to do some simple math to work out a ratio of an image. In my model I upload a header image, which also stores the width and height.

Using these values I create a ratio to be used on the frontend. When I show this value it returns 0. I have also tried using filters such as floatformat and it does nothing.

My Image dimensions are - Width: 1920px, Height: 1098.

I'm generating the ratio like so:

height / width.

I expect a value of: 0.571875

As mentioned previously it just returns 0 when on the frontend. If I use floatformat it just returns 0.00 etc.. I know the values are there because they are returned ok.

Here is some example code used in my Model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    header_width     = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    header_height    = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    header           = models.ImageField(width_field='header_width',height_field='header_height')

    def ratio (self):
        return self.header_height / self.header_width
```

Then in my template I'm doing something like this:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.header }}" data-ratio="{{ article.ratio }}" alt="header image">
```

Hopefully that is enough info. If not, I'll try and add more if you need it.

Thanks!

Comment: Python 2? If you divide two integers in python, it'll truncate. You should cast one of your integers to a float right before dividing (ie `float(self.header_height) / self.header_width`)

Comment: Did you realize that there is a built-in [`widthratio`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio) template tag?

Comment: Another option is to use `from __future__ import division`, so you can get a float result with just integer arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using python 2.7, the `/` operator performs an integer division when both operand are integer. You most likely want to write:

```
return float(self.header_height) / float(self.header_width)
```

Comment: Great! This did the trick. Good to know about how the / operator works in Python 2.7. Thanks.